# Retrieve Data from Firestore and Pass it to a variable. Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i would like to ask how can I retrieve the data from the Firestore and send it to a double.

This is the code where I retrieve the data from Firestore.

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('locations')
            .snapshots()
            .listen((driverLocation){
          driverLocation.documents.forEach((dLocation){
            dLocation.data['Latitude'] = latitude;
            dLocation.data['Longitude'] = longitude;
            print(latitude);
          });
        });
```

I store it inside the `dLocation` and when i `print(dLocation.data)` it will display the latitude and longitude in the Firestore. But when i pass it to the `double latitude` and `double longitude` it returns null.

```
busStop.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('driverLocation')
            ,
            draggable: false,
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            onTap: () {
            },
            position: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
          ));
```

Then i would like to pass the data that is in the `double latitude` and `double longitude` into the marker so that the marker will move accordingly to the latitude and longitude in the Firestore.

Everything that is happening here is in a `initState()`.

**If theres anything you would want to ask please feel free to do so as i do not have any idea on how to convey my question. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it in the wrong way. Right now you are assigning the value of `latitude` (which is null) to the value of `dLocation.data['latitude']`. What you want to do is this:

```
latitude = dLocation.data['latitude'];
longitude = dLocation.data['longitude'];
```

with this change, the value of `dLocation.data['latitude']` will be assigned to `latitude` and the value of `dLocation.data['longitude']` will be assigned to `longitude` variable

**Update:**

To get new markers and show them on the screen with `latitude` and `longitude` values, you can do something like this:

```
@override
void initState(){
Firestore.instance
            .collection('locations')
            .snapshots()
            .listen((driverLocation){
          //busStop = []; removes all the old markers and you don't get duplicate markers with different coordinates
          driverLocation.documents.forEach((dLocation){
            dLocation.data['Latitude'] = latitude;
            dLocation.data['Longitude'] = longitude;
            busStop.add(
               Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId('driverLocation')
                  ,
                  draggable: false,
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  position: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
          )); //you need to check for duplicate markers here. you can do it by giving each marker an unique id and check for the same marker in the list so you don't get duplicate markers.
          });
         setState((){}); //rebuilds the widget tree after adding the markers to the busStop list
        });

}
```

What's happening here is you add the markers to the busStop list and after adding all the markers, you call setState and the widget tree rebuilds the screen with the latest data. You might need to check for duplicate markers because they might be re-added to the `busStop` list. Or you can simply remove all the old markers and add the new ones by using `busStop = [];` before adding to `busStop`

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps me solve the issue of sending the `dLocation` data into `longitude` and `latitude` but when I uses the variable in the `Marker` function it returns null again. I have no idea how. Sorry for causing any inconvenience.

Comment: No problem. You can call setState() after assigning the values to latitude and longitude so your widget tree will be built again with the new values

Comment: so you mean like i will need to call a setState() inside a initState()?

Comment: any example of it? I search the internet and didn't find much as I don't really understand the meaning of it.

Comment: in order to have any change on the UI, you need to call setState. If you're building any widget by using the busStop list, in order to have the latest list with the latest items, you need to update it somehow so that's when you call setState. Because of that your widget tree will be created again with the latest items of the busStop list.

Comment: hmmmm i understand the concept what you saying is the setState() will be able to help to rebuild the widget as there are new information coming but i don't really know where should I put it.

Comment: have a look at my updated answer and see if it helps you

Comment: thank you so much this solve my question. Sorry for disturbing you. Have a nice day and be safe. God bless you good sir.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. please upvote my answer as well if it's possible

Comment: sorry havent met the 15 reputations yet. Im really sorry that I can't upvote it. Sorry